# How do I manage two internet lines going into one router at home?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, internet-connection, switch

I have a normal home WiFi network with some 10-15 devices connected. I have one regular use 2Mbps ADSL internet source and one high-speed 50Mbps cable line. I don't need to use both simultaneously, as one is unlimited and the other is limited. I simply need to pick one of the two and continue working.

Currently, I physically go to the router, plug out the LAN cable from one modem and put it into another. It's actually easy and it doesn't need any more config, so I haven't bothered to change this. But it would be nice to be able to pick between two via a web UI or something simpler.

I'm picturing a solution similar to a KVM switch but for LAN cables. There are dual-WAN (or multi-WAN) routers, but most of them seem to be built for automatic load balancing, so those are out.

I don't want to set up a proxy, because that will require too much config.

I don't want two separate WiFi routers because, like I said, I have several devices connected to to the network, which would be inaccessible from the other network. The devices are a healthy mix of Windows, Mac, Android, RPi and other devices including a smart TV and an Xbox 360.

What kind of a solution can you suggest?

Comment: If you have an OpenWrt-capable device, you can most likely set it up as a MultiWAN router, too.

Comment: Hi aalaap. Unfortunately, questions seeking product recommendations are off-topic on Super User. Can you [edit] your question to rephrase it in such a way that it doesn't ask for product recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

You can use two routers in the same LAN. Set DHCP on for the one you want to be the default. Leave it off in the other.

You can then switch to the non-default network just by changing your default gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Same here and my suggested solution is get both connected to your computer, then find the interface code (mine 12 and 14) . Use command to disable one and enable the other(saving as a batch file) with elevated priv. Afterwards all you need to do is just double click the bat file~